# Difference between using Drawable and decoding resource directly

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm using a bitmap resource to mask another image using `DST_IN` transfer mode.  This is the bitmap:

[image]

(You probably can't see it because it's white and transparent.)

If I load it like this, everything works as expected:

```
mMaskBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mMaskId);
```

But if I load it like this, it's as though the mask image were entirely transparent:

```
mMaskDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(mMaskId);    
mMaskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mMaskCanvas = new Canvas(mMaskBitmap);
mMaskDrawable.draw(mMaskCanvas);
```

What's the difference?

The bitmaps produced both ways are config `ARGB_8888`, density 320, and 512x512.  The size is strange because the resource file is 256x256, but it's the same for both.

I want to use the `Drawable` approach so the resource can be a ninepatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this before calling `draw(...)`:

```
mMaskDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
```

I could've sworn this was one of the first things I tried, but anyhow, it works now.  Maybe I did something wrong when I tried to clean and rebuild before.